# Most efficient way to use and communicate with many threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am coding an application that runs many threads in the background which have to report back to the main thread so it can update a table in the interface. In the past, the worker threads were ordinary separate classes (named Citizen) which I have ran from the main thread using something like

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(citizen.ProcessActions)).Start();
```

where ProcessActions function was the main function which did all the background work. Before actually starting the thread, I would register event handlers so the Citizen threads could log/report some stuff to the interface. Usually, there are tens of these Citizen threads (around 50) and they're pretty big classes - each has it's own HTTP client and it browses the web.

Is this a good way to do manage threads? Probably not, to be frank; I'm pretty sure  the threads aren't gracefully exiting - once the ProcessActions function gets done, I remove the event handlers and that's it - the memory usage keeps rising with each new Citizen started.

**What would be the best way to manage many (50+) threads, with which you have to communicate often?** I believe I wouldn't have to worry much about thread safety for Citizen variables as I wouldn't be accessing them from other threads but it's own thread.

Comment: What version of C# are you using?

Comment: Thread's should be killed as soon as they finish, something must be keeping them alive...

Comment: I am using C# 4.0. Could the event handlers keep them alive? Perhaps I'm not deleting them properly.

Comment: Are these threads performing some IO? How long do they normally run before completing?

Comment: Hm, they do log to a .txt file. But I close the streams ... They normally run for about 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a thread pool.  [Here's an MSDN article on them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and that should be available in C# 4.0.

The idea would be to create a thread pool, set its count to some high number(say 50), and then start assigning threads to tasks.  If the pool needs to expand, it can, but by declaring a high number up front, you get all the expensive creation of threads out of the way.

It might be beneficial to 'queue' tasks that you want to get done, and assign those tasks as threads become available.

Also, memory leaks can be hard to find, but I would start by testing the simple case:  Take out all threads(just run one Citizen after another from the main thread) and let it run for a long time.  If it's still leaking memory, your thread management isn't the issue.

Comment: A queue would be beneficial in assigning task priorities as well.